# Bike comes with frame integrated bolt seatpost clamp - can I cut it off and use QR?

Tags: frames, seatpost

I've got a Marin Pine Mountain 1 2016 - it comes with a frame integrated bolt seatpost clamp. Is it possible to cut this off and use a QR seatpost clamp instead?

Bike :

[image: https://cdnmos-bikeradar.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/news/2015/10/02/untitled--1-of-20--1477320063432-189chhxeyob0n-630-80.jpg]

Seat Clamp :

[image: https://cdnmos-bikeradar.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/news/2015/10/02/untitled--7-of-20--1477320063418-1krdx88edhrqw-630-354.jpg]

Comment: I've added some stock images - do they match what your bike looks like ?  If not, feel free to revert the change and add your own bike photo.

Comment: I'd be careful about making permanent modifications to your frame as it may affect the warranty.

Comment: Is there a specific need for quick release? Are you expecting different people to be riding this bike day to day?  If not, how often do you expect to change it that a quick release would be helpful?

Comment: QR works as a simple, cheap and robust dropper post. But why not just use a QR bolt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it's possible to hacksaw the clamp bosses off and then file the seat tube round and smooth so that a quick release clamp would slip over it.

Before taking such drastic action - which will significant hurt the resale value of the bike if you care about that - perhaps try to find a QR lever and skewer that will work with the existing clamp bosses.

Comment: If the OP's bike matches the pictures i would be weary of hacksawing the existing clamp, doing so would move the new clamp very close to the top tube and repeatedly clamping and unclamping that tube so close to the weld may weaken it over a long period of time. Or maybe not, but i wouldn't want to test it.

Comment: @NateW I was assuming the OP would cut off the bosses and smooth the tubes, not cut the sear tube  below the bosses, which I would not recommend - bit then I would not recommend any drastic mods to this frame anyway.

Comment: Ahhh okay yeah i totally misread that.... carry on sir. ;)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about cutting off the bosses. I've seen it done before, but I wondered if there was any design reason for them vs QR